# How can I correctly retrieve an ImageView declared into a fragment layout from a class that extends Fragment and not Activity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-imageview

I have the following problem trying to retrieve a layout element into a class.

So I have the following situation:

1) I have this **fragment_screen_slide_page.xml** file that contains the element of a fragment that is shown into a view:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Dummy content. -->
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/carbonara" />

        <TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
            style="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

As you can see it contains the **ImageView** element having **id=imageView1**.

Then I have this **ScreenSlidePageFragment** that works on the previous fragment, I have something like this:

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

    ................................................................
    ................................................................
    ................................................................

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ................................................................
        ................................................................
        ................................................................
        // Retrieve the reference of the ImageView element of the layout having id=imgSlide:
        ImageView imgSlideView = (ImageView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        ................................................................
        ................................................................
        ................................................................
    }

    ................................................................
    ................................................................
    ................................................................
}
```

As you can see, into the **onCreate()** method I am trying to retrieve the **ImageView** refernce of the element having **id=imageView1** defined into the **fragment_screen_slide_page.xml** file, by this instruction:

```
ImageView imgSlideView = (ImageView) this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
```

I have done this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imageView1) because the **ScreenSlidePageFragment** extends **Fragment** and not **Activity** so it have not inherited the **findViewById()** method and I can't do diretly **findViewById(R.id.imageView1);** as I done into a class that extends **Activity**.

The problem is that doing in this way I obtain **null** as result.

Why? What am I missing? How can I correctly retrieve my **ImageView** declared into the **fragment_screen_slide_page.xml** file from the **ScreenSlidePageFragment** (that extends **Fragment** and not **Activity**)?

Comment: why don't you give the documentation a try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Try That:***
move your code from `oncreate` to the overriden `onCreateView`

```
public  View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page,container,false);
        ImageView imgSlideView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        return view;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call it within `onViewCreated`

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle  savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ImageView imgSlideView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `onCreate()`, you could override `onViewCreated()` and get your `ImageView` from there:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    ImageView imgSlideView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
}
```